# NetBeans IDE 8.2 + Maven 3.0.5 + Java EE 8 + First Cup of Java EE = javax.ws.rs not found

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish, maven-3, netbeans-8

I'm try to learn Java EE 8 using this guide https://javaee.github.io/firstcup/
I have followed this guide https://github.com/javaee/firstcup to setup the environment.
The problem is that: there are multiple match to the package javax.ws.rs through the "Search Dependency at Maven Repositories for javax.ws.rs" I get this:

- com.sun.jersey: jersey-bundle
- com.sun.jersey: jersey-core
- javax: javaee-api
- javax: javaee-web-api
- javax.ws.rs: javax.ws.rs-api
- org.glassfish.jersey: jax-rs-ri
- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles: jaxrs-ri

so what I should choose?

Answer (score 0):

javax.ws.rs: javax.ws.rs-api is the package to depend on for JAX-RS. javaee-api and javaee-web-api are all the javax packages for all of Java EE and Java EE web profile respectively, which includes JAX-RS. The jersey packages are for the reference implementation of JAX-RS, but you don't need to reference them if you are deploying to an application server, as they or an alternative implementation will be provided. They are there if you are going to be JAX-RS in a non-Java EE envrionment.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened an issue (https://github.com/javaee/firstcup/issues/10) on github to get help for improve the documentation on "First Cup of Java EE Tutorial".
However I think that for this example the most correct answer is to use the javaee-api package.